# What is the Intention of Constructor Parameters of type of an internal enum?: code from Programming principles and Practice using C++

Tags: c++, constructor, enums, member, static-members

I am having trouble using the constructors of the `Struct` below. Specifically the ones with the parameter of type `Color_type`.

It is my understanding that since the `enum` `Color_type` is defined within the `struct` `Color` providing something seemingly that could be accessed like `Color::Color_type::red`, but this does not work when I call the constructor with such a value, e.g., `Color p{Color::Color_type::red};`

I am confused about the intention of having this `enum` within the `struct` and providing constructors with parameters of this type. How would one constructing this object have access to those type definitions?

Would a better solution be to use a scoped `enum class` outside of the `struct` that is named the same, such that it provides the means to call the constructor like `Color p{Color::Color_type::red};`

The same questions extend to the `enum Transparency` as well.

This is a snippit of a grapics library provided by Bjarne Stroustrup in his book, *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2e*

```
struct Color {

    enum Color_type {
            red=FL_RED, blue=FL_BLUE, green=FL_GREEN,
            yellow=FL_YELLOW, white=FL_WHITE, black=FL_BLACK,
            magenta=FL_MAGENTA, cyan=FL_CYAN, dark_red=FL_DARK_RED,
            dark_green=FL_DARK_GREEN, dark_yellow=FL_DARK_YELLOW, dark_blue=FL_DARK_BLUE,
            dark_magenta=FL_DARK_MAGENTA, dark_cyan=FL_DARK_CYAN
            };
    enum Transparency { invisible = 0, visible=255 };

    Color(Color_type cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }
    Color(Color_type cc, Transparency vv) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(vv) { }
    Color(int cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }
    Color(Transparency vv) :c(Fl_Color()), v(vv) { }

    int as_int() const { return c; }
    char visibility() const { return v; }
    void set_visibility(Transparency vv) { v=vv; }

    private:
    unsigned char v;        // 0 or 1 for now
    Fl_Color c;
};
```

Comment: You can use `Color::red` instead of `Color::Color_type::red`.

Answer (score 0):

With help from this [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349159/what-is-the-intention-of-constructor-parameters-of-type-of-an-internal-enum-co?noredirect=1#comment69900015_41349159) I was able to further test and discover that `Color test{Color::red};` does indeed compile.

The immediate error I was receiving was from using the `using` declaration in a class definition to inherit the constructors of a base class.

One of the members of the that class was of type `Color` and it complained about using an constructor that was implicitly deleted because of an ill-formed definition.

It was ill-formed because `Color::Color_type` was not defined within the scope of the class I was defining. Once I fully qualified the type with the containing namespace, I was able to compile.

```
namespace
{
struct Color { // Same as before}

struct Striped_rectangle : Rectangle // details ommitted for Rectangle
{
using Rectangle::Rectangle;
// details ommited
private:
Color stc{Color::Color_type::red};
}
```

Both of the following initializations for the member `stc` in `Striped_rectangle` will compile: `Color stc{Graph_lib::Color::red};`
and
`Color stc{Graph_lib::Color::Color_type::red};`